# Extract pixel values at given point dataset and if masked find the nearest pixel value

Tags: google-earth-engine, extract, pixel

I need to extract the values at each pixel foe a feature collection from an image and if they are masked the value at nearest pixel,
my feature collection is named table and the image collection I am using is Landsat 7 Collection 1 Tier 1 Annual NDVI Composite

```js
var mapfunc = function(feat) {
 var geom = feat.geometry()
 var addProp = function(img, f) {
   var newf = ee.Feature(f)
   var date = img.date().format()
   var value = img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), geom, 30).get("NDVI")
   return ee.Feature(ee.Algorithms.If(value,
                                  newf.set(date, ee.String(value)),
                                  newf.set(date, ee.String('No data'))))
  }
  var newfeat = ee.Feature(ndvi.iterate(addProp, feat))
  return newfeat
 };

 var newftNDVI = table.map(mapfunc);
```

This code extracts values at said pixels but does not extract the nearest pixel values for the masked ones.